# How can I generate and sign session keys and insert it to the keystore before starting my node?

Tags: validator

I don't want to keep my keys on the server. I am concerned with best practices whenever it comes to running anything on the cloud, and as such, if I am running a validator node, I realise that I need to provide my keys or at least sign session keys and insert it into the keystore. Can someone show me the best way to go about this?

1. Generate a stash/controller pair from a secret seed on local machine. Done.
2. Start a node on a cloud instance with `--validator` flag. Done.
3. Generate session keys by calling rotateKeys() like so : `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "author_rotateKeys", "params":[]}' http://localhost:9933`. Done.
4. How to sign this key and insert it into the keystore?
5. Anything else that's required for the block production/validation to begin?

Edit #1 : I see this tool https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/tree/master/packages/signer-cli for signing messages offline. Can it be used to sign a session key and send it to the chain keystore? Can someone show how if this is indeed possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can insert the pre-generated session keys to the node by calling rpc `author_insertKey`. However you will need to take care of the encoding of the keys, since the content of the session keys in different chains may vary. I would suggest to insert the key with Polkadot.js. Here's an example:

https://github.com/Phala-Network/khala-parachain/blob/main/scripts/js/insert_session_key.js